# Laravel Excel 3.1 : Import, modify, download

Tags: php, mysql, excel, laravel-excel, laravel-5.8

I'm struggeling with Laravel-Excel 3.1.
I'm not able to modify a file. My file has two sheets (called template). I want to load the document, modify it and let the user download it.

The Excel file was not created by me, I just need to fill it with data.
For exemple from this one : 
[image]
to this one :
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Try to add your related code with description.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not sure if this will still be helpful, but here some code to do this.

```php
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\RegistersEventListeners;

class TestExport implements WithEvents

{
    use Exportable, RegistersEventListeners;

    public static function beforeExport(BeforeExport $event)
    {
        // get your template file
        $event->writer->reopen(new \Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\LocalTemporaryFile(storage_path('app/exports/report-front-page.xlsx')),Excel::XLSX);
        $event->writer->getSheetByIndex(0);
        
        // fill with information
        $event->getWriter()->getSheetByIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1','Some Information');
        $event->getWriter()->getSheetByIndex(0)->setCellValue('G4', 'Some Information');

        return $event->getWriter()->getSheetByIndex(0);
    }   

}
```

Answer (score -2):

use excel package

```
use Excel;
```

Here you can pass data

```
$getdata = values from database or directly get from user.
$headings= you have to pass heading of each column
```

Export data into excel

```
public function getExport($get_data, $headings)
{

    Excel::create(('excel name', function ($excel) use ($get_data, $headings) {
        $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function ($sheet) use ($get_data, $headings) {

            $sheet->fromArray($get_data, null, 'A1', false, false);
            $sheet->prependRow(1, $headings);

        });
    })->export('xls');
}
```

Comment: ALL Laravel Excel 2.* methods are deprecated and we cannot be able to use them in 3.0 and Excel::create() is one of them.